# Read File, file "does not exist"

Tags: java, file

The file I am reading, is not being fetched. I don't know, if its an issue with the operating system I am working on, but just to let you know, I am on a macOs environment. Anyways, I have this .txt file, that I'm passing its path into the class "File" constructor. I am using conditions to test if it exists or not, I get a message "File does not exist". I am confused to why its not being reached.

```
try {
        File file = new File("StudentInfo.txt");

        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your file in relation to you project? "StudentInfo.txt" probably isn't where you think it is.

Comment: Is the file in the JVM's current working directory? If not, you need to supply an absolute or relative path.

Comment: The file name is relative to your [working directory](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+working+directory), which depends on how you launch the program.

Comment: I've right clicked the file to see its direct path, but all I get is "studentInformation.txt", is there a way I can do it through the "Terminal"?

Comment: It should be exactly `StudentInfo.txt` - the name should be the same

Comment: Did you try fetching the file using Buffered Reader?

Comment: No I haven't @PrateekAggarwal, Ill give that a shot\

Comment: I think using BufferedReader wont help. Buffered reader will help you reading the contents of the file once you open it. So you should focus on opening the file first. Check the current directory and filename first. Once you are able to do it, then try using BufferedReader or Scanner to read it.

Comment: "FileNotFoundException" @PrateekAggarwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a Finder window, go to the file StudentInfo.txt, select this file with the mouse then press ALT key, then right click and select "Copy StudentInfo.txt as pathname". After that, you have the full path of that file in your clipboard.

Or, using the terminal, go to the directory containing your file using `cd` command then type `pwd` to get the current path.

Comment: Can I find the full path through the Terminal